# Разблокировка кнопки отправки формы при ее корректном заполнении

Tags: javascript, jquery

Уважаемые кодеры!

Вопрос мой заключается в следующем.. есть форма регистрации, на которой проводится ряд проверок на правильность заполнения полей этой формы, помимо этого я хочу блокировать кнопку отправки, пока все поля не будут заполнены так, как надо

Для блокировки кнопки отправки добавил след. кусок кода:

```
$('input[type="text"]').ready(function()
{
    var submit = $('input[name="submit"]');

    var input_login = $('input[name="login"]');
    var input_password = $('input[name="password"]');

/* в коде представлены далеко не все проверки, но суть вопроса это не меняет */
    if (input_login.val().length < 6 || input_password.val().length < 6)
    {
        submit.attr('disabled', true);
    }
    else
    {
        submit.attr('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

который (в теории!) должен при не выполнении условий в if () делать кнопку доступной для нажатия, чего, собственно, не происходит

Что именно не дает уйти коду в выполнение условия else {} не понимаю, т.е. при вводе пары логин/пароль, каждых длиною в 6 символов, кнопка по-прежнему остается заблокированной

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с этой проблемой

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш обработчик не выполняется тогда, когда Вы думаете, что он выполняется.

```js
$('input[type="text"]').ready(function() {
  console.log("in ready");
});

$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {
  console.log("in keyup");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: Игорь, спасибо Вам! Ваш ответ натолкнул меня на правильное написание кода

Comment: @ElRey Пожалуйста. Успехов.